# React Nesting Router is not working in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-router-dom

I am using ERB (Electron React Boilerplate) and trying to use React Router Dom v6.2.1.
So I am using Router with MemoryRouter because BrowserRouter is not a good way to build a windows desktop application.
Here I face one issue. Nesting Router is not working in MemoryRouter.
If I use this in BrowserRouter, it's okay.
Here is my code and please let me know how to make nesting router in MemoryRouter.

```
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import AppLayout from './layouts/AppLayout';
import BaseLayout from './layouts/BaseLayout';
import Store from './redux/Store';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <Router>
        <BaseLayout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<AppLayout/>} />
            <Route path="/auth" element={<AuthLayout/>}>
              <Router path="login" element={<Login />} />
              <Router path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
              <Router path="forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BaseLayout>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I got the warning console like this `Location 'login' not found`

Please help me with this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Here is the additional Code.

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router";

const AuthLayout = () => {
  return(
    <Outlet />
  )
}

export default AuthLayout;



import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";

const AppLayout = () => {
  const access = localStorage.getItem('access')
  const username = localStorage.getItem('username')
  let navigate = useNavigate()
  if (!access || !username){
    useEffect(() => {
      navigate('/auth/login')
    }, [])
  } else {
    useEffect(() => {
      navigate('/home/dashboard')
    })
  }
  return(
    <div>
      AppLayout
    </div>
  )
}

export default AppLayout;
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a `"/login"` path, or a `"/auth/login"` path? Can you please add all relevant code you are having an issue working with to your question, specifically the `AuthLayout` component? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I want to make the path of "/auth/login", "/auth/path" and AuthLayout will have some navigation that redirects to Login and Signup, Forgot Password Page.
Is it possible in MemoryRouter? - @DrewReese

Comment: Can you add your `AuthLayout` component to your question so we can see how it's rendering the nested routes? Can you add the code where you are attempting to link to these routes?

Comment: I just added my code - AuthLayout. Thank you for your considering of my question.
-- @DrewReese

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to ensure that the `AuthLayout` component was rendering an `Outlet` for the nested `Route` components to be rendered into. What I don't see yet are the links or where you are navigating to routes. Can you add those as well?

Comment: Is it good to add the whole code here? I think it's not good way to add all code in this stackoverflow, but anyways, I added the whole code now. Please check the code again.
Thank you again, @DrewReese

Comment: As @lanxion just pointed out, it seems you've a typo for the nested routes, they are `Router` components instead of `Route` components. Is this just a copy/paste error, or is this your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a typo to me. You're supposed to nest `Route` with another `Route`, you seem to be nesting `Router` instead (which is the `MemoryRouter` you are importing). Just changing inner `Router` to `Route` should fix it.

```
<Provider store={Store}>
      <Router>
        <BaseLayout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<AppLayout/>} />
            <Route path="/auth" element={<AuthLayout/>}>
              <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
              <Route path="forgot" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BaseLayout>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
```

Comment: Oh, fail ‍♂️ Yes, I totally agree. Should be voted closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" then.

Comment: Yes. It's really working, I am very happy to meet you and another of my mentor, @lanxion
Please give me good answers in the future again.